# Jquery post error sending an Object with 2 methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm trying to introduce OOP in my javascript & I got and error when trying to send an object (class) with two methods with Jquery $.post. The weird thing is that when I remove one of the method (only one remain) I have no error.

The object definition:

```
    function Project(project, date) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.project_id = project;
    this.year = date;
    this.percent = 0;
    this.sales = 0;
    this.purchase = 0;
    this.user_update = 'Cubic';
    this.action = '';
}
```

The methods (first one is the one that cause the conflict):

```
Project.prototype.refreshProject = function () {
    $j("[data-project='" + this.project_id + "'][data-year='" + this.year + "'].pl-sales").text(formatNumber(this.sales));
    $j("[data-project='" + this.project_id + "'][data-year='" + this.year + "'].pl-purchases").text(formatNumber(this.purchase));
    $j("[data-project='" + this.project_id + "'][data-year='" + this.year + "'].pl-margen").text(formatNumber(this.sales - this.purchase));
    calcTotales();
}

Project.prototype.getCorrector = function () {
    corrector = [];
    yearIndex = periods.indexOf(this.year) + 1;
    corrector[0] = stringtoNum($j("[data-rowproject='" + this.project_id + "'].row-sales").text());
    corrector[1] = stringtoNum($j("[data-rowproject='" + this.project_id + "'].row-purchases").text());

    for (var i = yearIndex; i < periods.length; i++) {
        corrector[0] -= stringtoNum($j("[data-project='" + this.project_id + "'][data-year='" + periods[i] + "'].pl-sales").text());
        corrector[1] -= stringtoNum($j("[data-project='" + this.project_id + "'][data-year='" + periods[i] + "'].pl-purchases").text());
    }
    for (var i = yearIndex; i > 1; i--) {
        // modificar year - 1
    }
    return corrector;
}
```

the post section:

```
recordper = new Project(parseInt($j(this).data('project')), parseInt($j(this).data('year')));
......
$j.post("pl_agency/ajax_request.php",recordper, function (respuesta, status) {
                console.log(respuesta + ' : ' + status);
});
recordper.refreshProject();
```

the error: The object (recordper) is undefined when refreshProject() is called

thanks for your help & excuse my english

Comment: What is the error? Are you trying to `POST` a JavaScript plain object or a string?

Comment: I'm afraid not..

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What does `console.log(typeof recordper, recordper)` print?

Comment: return ..object 
Object { id: 1, project_id: 6, year: 2019, percent: 10, sales .......

Comment: Yep. I tried JSON.stringify(recordper) but then php was not working properly. $_POST is something like this " [{"id":1,"project_id":6,"year":2019,"percent":10,"sales":32073_600000000002,"purchase":1392,"user_update":"Cubic","action":"updateadv"}] =>"

Comment: The post will send it like a form post.  id, project_id, etc.  The functions or methods will be sent refreshProject: undefined, getCorrector: undefined.  Since you aren't doing anything with them on the server side that should be fine.  There was no errors pushed out to the console?

Comment: yes, Inside the method refreshProject() I call a global function formatNumber(num) When I use $j.post the console say that num is undefined

Comment: Can you change this: formatNumber(this.sales - this.purchase) to this: formatNumber(this.sales) - formatNumber(this.purchase)

Comment: Tx but this doesn't solve the issue. Not even removing the entire line

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I found a shortcut. I don't know if there are a smarter way to do it but that's working for me.

I pass all the properties (not the methods) to a new object and send this in $.post

```
newObj = {
    id : recordper.id,
    project_id : recordper.project_id,
    .......       
};
$j.post("pl_agency/ajax_request.php",newObj, function (respuesta, status) {
...... }
```

Not very proud since I like to minimize code, but It works. Still open to better solutions. Tx